# Oracle sequence number error on store procedure error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

I have this query working fine when I test it

```
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (EXAMPLE.SEQ_EXAMPLE_ID.NEXTVAL, 'TEST', 'TEST');
```

But when I try to use the same query inside a stored procedure I got a

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (EXAMPLE.PK_SOME_TABLE) violated
```

If I select from `some_table` using the sequence number generated, there's nothing returned.

I already checked the constrains on the table `SELECT * FROM all_indexes WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'some_table';` and everything seems to be fine.

-- edited

We solved the problem re creating the sequence, still not sure what the main problem was, but deleting and creating the sequence again solved the issue.

Comment: Presumably you mean `nextval` rather than just `next`. Beyond that there's nothing we can suggest unless you show us the whole procedure, or at least post a reproducible test case. Because this should work, which means there's a problem in how you've written the procedure: we can't spot the problem without seeing the source.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two operation you can do it with Sequence. Next is not a valid statement.

1. To find the next value ( sequence.NEXTVAL )
2. To find the current value ( sequence.CURRVAL )

Once the sequence is created, next value should be called at least once before calling current value. To read further about sequence, please click the below link.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF00253